# html select with search/filter that isn't unbearably slow on Internet Explorer 9+

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer

I'm working on a web application that requires a user to select a company name from a list.  The list contains approximately 5000 companies.  If I use a standard HTML select control, the performance is fine in all browsers.  However, scrolling through a list that long isn't really user friendly.  I tried using several different jQuery based filterable select controls, but every one of them was extremely slow and unusable in Internet Explorer (targeting 9+)...

https://github.com/bseth99/jquery-ui-extensions

https://github.com/harvesthq/chosen

https://github.com/ehynds/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget

Is there any way to do a filterable list in Internet Explorer where the performance isn't terrible?

Comment: Chosen would be my plugin of choice, but if that is too slow, write your own that doenst pull down the full 5000 until you scroll to that level. or a search box instead. 5000 items in a select is just unpractical.

Comment: the list doesn't have to be in an HTML select.  I'm looking for any solution at this point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an MS-Connect thread discussing IE's slow creation and sorting of select options.  Maybe you'd like to add a comment there.

https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/856580/very-slow-option-creation-and-access

Here's the demo it contains.  Give the [10000] button a click.  Compare Firefox performance (less than 1 sec) with IE11 (more than 2 minutes).

https://6eb9911a8fb76ee796387bdc5cd84d47cb7f2c1e.googledrive.com/host/0B8BLd2qPPV7XaTNmaHVkckt1UGM

@The person who defaced this thread "-1".  If it weren't for IE's atrocious performance, sorting a select with 5000 options would be a totally practical thing to do.